# Stop capturing after reaching a line with only uppercase letters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture only the words between titles that are always all caps (in the example below, 'SONG' and 'AT BAIA'). When using this, I will know what the first title is (i.e. 'SONG'), but I won't know what the second title is (i.e. 'AT BAIA').

### Example

```
And I lie listening awake?    
SONG    
You are as gold    
The half-opened flowers    
For your face is as fair as rain,    
Yet as rain that lies clear    
Casts light for a shadow.    
AT BAIA    
I should have thought
```

I've managed to capture everything below 'SONG' using:

`SONG\s*((.*\s.*)*)`

But can't figure out how to stop when I reach a line with only capital letters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(?<=SONG\s)([\s\S]+?(?=^[A-Z ]+$))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match SONG followed by capturing in a group all the lines that do not start with 2 uppercase chars

```
^SONG\b.*((?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]{2}).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wwujYD/1)

Or if the line can contain only contain captital letters and should also start with one:

```
^SONG\b.*((?:\r?\n(?![A-Z][A-Z ]*$).*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `SONG\b.*` Match Song, word boundary and the rest of the line
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?![A-Z][A-Z ]*$).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not contain only uppercase chars
  - `)*` Close the group and match all the lines
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2J9jUM/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/d8PaQK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SONG[\s\S]*(?=^[A-Z][A-Z ]+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JAwfgu/2)

You will also need the `re.MULTILINE` flag for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a more simple regex `SONG(?:.|\n)*[A-Z]{3,}\s+\n`

- start with `SONG`
- read any content
- stop when the line ends with an uppercase word (at least 3 uppercase letter, you can choose the size you  need)

## [`REGEX DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/UsefulKnobbyCgi)